# Smart Card based Remote attendance web application in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, winforms, web-services

My latest project is on SmartCard based Attandance Application.The framework would be .NET (ASP.NET / C# )

So scenario is something like :- the client has 3 food chain stores named as A,B,C.
 All stores will have a smart card based enterance system for employees ( thats what I propose intially, because there is no HR Manager )

So when a employees enters or leaves  the stores (all three)
  Then their log In / Log out info,Names, Log-in/Out Time will be avaialable to the Owner  on remote location (probably on the Website Admin panel where owner  can log into to the admin panel & then he can check status of the employees, Or we can send him a mail  )

That's all.
Although my question is not very specific & but I just want your views & suggestion on this as project is in its planning stage.

What should be the best approach like using a Windows based software to save employees record / data & later send it to web site through webservice.
Is there any specific .NET based framework to read smart card data ?
Also I need other infomation about smart card like are there any card writer avilable to set employee name & id on his card. 
I am not thinking of writing employee smart Card by ourself but if this case then how It could be done ?

I appriciate your valuable comments & guidlines.

Comment: Just log the access times, the present that information, in a way the manager can use it.  Broadcasting the certificate for the smart card is going to be tough.  .NET has the built-in support for Smart cards.

Answer (score 2):

I worked on a project before with a similar need.

The plan we came up with was the following.

1. All Remote locations would be outfitted with a small server which would handle the SmartCard part at the side and transmit all data to a remote server.
2. A Server would be set up to store all the data and provide it on request.

This solution is scalable since all new locations would have a server which again transmits all the data to the main server for persistent storage.

If the Internetconnection to one location would go down, the server on side would still be able to handle the access via SmartCard and store the information until such time as the Internetconnection would become available again and the send the data.

As to the cards: We were supposed to use RFID-Cards. We had a partner which provided both the cards and all the terminals and writers.

Comment: Thanks Sören really helpful, It would be really great if you you provide more information. Also what about card writers?  Now I am thinking to first create a windows application on .Net that will read card & store data in sql server . After that I have to create a ASP.NET webservice So the idea is to access web service through Windows application ( at remote location, ie at Store A ) & send the saved SQL data to the Server twice a day If internet is available.  please suggest if it correct..